# FFmpeg audio stream output no sound when a video ends for merging

Tags: ffmpeg

I concatenated horizontally two videos which have different durations with FFmpeg.
FFmpeg works fine and generates a video file as a result.
It works fine when both videos are playing.
However, when a shorter video ends, there is no sound output.
I googled a lot but I couldn't find any post to solve this problem.

Here's the FFmpeg code that I used.

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack=inputs=2[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output
```

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The amerge filter ends with the shorter stream. Use amix instead

```
[0:a][1:a]amix=2[a]
```